# Close Form when not clicking on it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to know if there is any event when you click on the rest of the screen and not the Windows Form the Form closes. Is it because of the `ShowDialog()`?

My Main Form is just with a notifyIcon and when I click it I call `Form1.ShowDialog();`

Main.cs:

```
private void ShowForm1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        form1.Left = Cursor.Position.X;
        form1.Top = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom - form1.Height;
        form1.ShowDialog();
}
```

Form1.cs:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        label1.Text = "Test";
}
```

Comment: Yeah it's lose focus.

Comment: Do you mean "click somewhere on the form that called `ShowDialog`" (i.e., when you get the beep) or click somewhere outside of the application's windows

Comment: outside the called with Form1.ShowDialog() form like taskbar or other open apps

Comment: Are you wedded to `ShowDialog` for some reason.  Windows dialog boxes do weird things.  You can't even use "Mouse Capture" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/mouse-capture-in-windows-forms) to pick up a mouse click outside the dialog box.  If you brought up the form non-modally (`Show`, not `ShowDialog`) mouse capture would probably work

Comment: i tried it with Show() too but it did not change. where do i have to put the LostFocus()? in Main.cs or Form1.cs?

Comment: Focus, mouse capture and activation/deactivation in Win32 windows are complicated and intertwined.  What you are looking for is deactivation (when a window loses focus for any reason it gets deactivated).  Check out my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the dialog box non-modally, not modally.  Think about it, when you run it modally, the dialog box takes over the UI and plays games with mouse-clicks elsewhere, preventing you from running.  You don't want it to be modal anyway.

I created a simple Windows form with a button that includes this handler to open a small `AutoCloseDialog` form I created (and populated with a few controls):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dlg = new AutoCloseDialog();
    dlg.Show(this);       //NOTE: Show(), not ShowDialog()
}
```

Then, in the `AutoCloseDialog` form, I wired up the `Deactivate` event.  I did it in the designer (where this code is generated):

```
this.Deactivate += new System.EventHandler(this.AutoCloseDialog_Deactivate);
```

Finally, here is the handler for the `Deactivate` event.

```
private void AutoCloseDialog_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

I think this does what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a similar function like this, which closes the Form if the Form lost focus (in `Form1.cs`)

```
public void Form_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}
```

and then you add the LoseFocus EventHandler (in `Form1.Designer.cs`):

```
this.LostFocus += new EventHandler(Form_LostFocus);
```

Comment: didnt change anything :/